# How to register driver to use headless chrome?

Tags: selenium, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I'm not sure how to set up my `spec_helper` so that it can take advantage of headless Chrome. I've looked for resources online and I can't seem to dig up anything useful. Has anyone successfully taken advantage of headless chrome with just the installation of chromedriver and no other required setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be using at least Chrome 59 for headless mode - https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5678767817097216 - which I believe is currently the dev channel.  If you are then all you need to do is pass the 'headless' command line option through to Chrome.  You can do that while registering your driver with something like

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, args: ['headless'])
end
```

Note: Capybara has not been tested with this yet, and I would guess the current chromedriver may have some issues with Chrome 59 too

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I thought perhaps this was available in a stable release already.  I'll have the info for setting my `spec_helper` in my pocket.